# Stored procedure with DataReader

Tags: c#

When trying to clean up the code using a stored procedure "sp_receiptload"; the data isn't passing.

I would like to use a stored procedure to reduce the code line. Below is what i currently have which works. I want to use SqlCommand receiptload_cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_receiptload") which contains all of the queries in a single batch query. I want to remove using multiple readers. When I tried implementing; using the nextresult did not move results. When I put a while infront of the first row the error was the reader is not open.

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand vendor_cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ICVENDOR ORDER BY name;", sqlconn))
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = vendor_cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("vendor_id", typeof(int));
                    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    cb_vendor.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    cb_vendor.DisplayMember = "name";
                    cb_vendor.ValueMember = "vendor_id";
                    reader.Close();
                }
                using (SqlCommand hcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 H_ID FROM ICRECEIPTH ORDER BY h_id DESC", sqlconn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = hcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())//this is required to read - if more tan one block of data use while this .read is required to fetch the result
                    {
                        maxh_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        newh_id = maxh_id + 1;
                        double digits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(newh_id) + 1);
                        double num0 = 10 - digits;
                        string snum00 = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < num0; i++)
                        {
                            string snum0 = (i * 0).ToString();
                            snum00 = snum00 + snum0;
                        }
                        string docnum = "RCP" + snum00 + newh_id.ToString();
                        tb_docnum.Text = docnum;

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT item_id FROM ICITEM", sqlconn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader1.Read())
                        {
                            items.Add(reader1.GetString(0));
                        }
                        reader1.Close();
                    }

                    dataGridView1.Columns["Item"].Visible = false;
                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Item_cbcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    Item_cbcol.HeaderText = "Item";
                    Item_cbcol.Name = "Item_cbcol";
                    Item_cbcol.Items.Add("True");
                    Item_cbcol.DataSource = items.ToList();
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Item_cbcol);
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Item_cbcol"].DisplayIndex = 1;
                    Item_cbcol.AutoComplete = Enabled;
                    Item_cbcol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        row.Cells["Item_cbcol"].Value = row.Cells["Item"].Value;
                    }

                    tb_docnum.Enabled = false;

                }
                sqlconn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you used next Result.But here is how it should be used.Try this and let me know if it worked in your case

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT * FROM ICVENDOR ORDER BY name" +
          "SELECT TOP 1 H_ID FROM ICRECEIPTH ORDER BY h_id DESC"+
          "SELECT item_id FROM ICITEM",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //logic to read
            }               
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not start creating a stored procedure just for simple SELECT queries that return a set of records without any particular complex logic. It will be better probably for the performances but more complex for future maintenance.

Given the fact that you have different processing needs for each table retrieved and you have probably a limited amount of data to retrieve I would use a DataSet and a DataAdapter

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("........."))
{
    con.Open();
    string sqlText = @"SELECT name, vendor_id FROM ICVENDOR ORDER BY name;
                      SELECT TOP 1 H_ID FROM ICRECEIPTH ORDER BY h_id DESC;
                      SELECT item_id FROM ICITEM",
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    ProcessTableICVendor(ds.Tables[0]);
    ProcessTableICReceipt(ds.Tables[1]);
    ProcessTableICItem(ds.Tables[2]);
}
```

Notice that I have changed the first query to return only the fields needed. So you don't need an intermediate table to initialize the combobox.

Of course the ProcessTableICxxx methods are placeholders for the code you have already written